# Changing programmatically brightness while using auto mode has no effect in Android

Tags: android, settings, brightness

I've written code to create DialogPreference that should be working similar to default Android brightness setting dialog.

It works perfect as long as brightness mode is set to `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL`. But when I change mode to `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC` the phone brightness does not take the value of `Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)` into account.

Let me show you an example:

1. I set brightness in Android settings to 255 and mode to automatic. The changes are reflected by the phone (as well as my app).
2. I set brightness in Android settings to 100 and mode to manual. The changes are reflected by the phone (as well as my app).
3. I set brightness in my app to 50 and mode is still manual. The changes are reflected by the phone (as well as my app).
4. I set brightness in my app to 50 and mode to automatic. Although I programmatically change current screen brightness to 50, the rest of my app and the phone itself (for example phone settings and home) has brightness 255 and mode to automatic (which I can check in Android settings). At the same time, `Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)` is still returning 50.

Here is my code. I as said, it's in a class that extends DialogPreference, thus the onCreateDialogView method.

```
private static int MAX_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE = 255;

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    View dialogView = super.onCreateDialogView();
    mAutomatic = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.automatic_brightness);
    mBrightnessBar = (SeekBar) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.brightness_bar);

    mBrightnessBar.setMax(MAX_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE);
    mAutomatic.setChecked(getBrightnessMode() == Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
    mBrightnessBar.setProgress(getBrightness());

    mAutomatic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                setAutomaticBrightness();
            } else {
                setManualBrightness();
            }
        }

    });
    mBrightnessBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (progress > 10) {
                setBrightness(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

    });
    return dialogView;
}

private void setBrightness(int value) {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value);

    // here I set current screen brightness programmatically
    Window window = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow();
    LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
    layoutpars.screenBrightness = value / (float) MAX_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE;
    window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
}

private int getBrightness() {
    try {
        return Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return MAX_BRIGHTNESS_VALUE;
    }
}

private void setAutomaticBrightness() {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
            Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
}

private void setManualBrightness() {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
            Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
}

private int getBrightnessMode() {
    try {
        return Settings.System.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE);
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC;
    }
}
```

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />` in my AndroidManifest.xml

Does anyone know what is going on? I have seen some Stack Overflow threads with similar problems, but none of them got any helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you set brightness mode to automatic. then you need to stop automatic brightness adjustment before sets brightness.
this code worked for me:

```
      public static void stopAutoBrightness(Activity activity) {
          android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(activity.getContentResolver(),
                  android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
                  android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it just works that way. If you set brightness mode to automatic by yourself, you cannot manipulate brightness level.

An example is here:
[BrightnessPreference code on grepcode.com for 4.1.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.2_r1/com/android/settings/BrightnessPreference.java#BrightnessPreference)
In this Preference brightness SeekBar is disabled when brightness mode is automatic.

Based on [BrightnessPreference code on grepcode.com for 4.4.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.2_r1/com/android/settings/BrightnessPreference.java#BrightnessPreference)
I came up with the following inflexible solution:

```
@Override
protected void onClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.settings.BrightnessPreferenceActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It just starts the Activity used in Android settings. It was good enough in my case.